# non-static variable .. cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java

I have initialized an array

```
    String s = sc.nextLine();
    String[] Question = s.split(" ");
```

then I have this while-loop calling a method/function

```
    while (y != x) {
        analyzer anlz = new analyzer();
        anlz.find(Question[y]);
        y = y + 1;
    }
```

but anlz.find(Question[y]) keeps getting a wrong mark saying that non-static variable Question cannot be referenced from a static context

and this is the function/method find(String[] q)

```
    public String find(String[] q) throws IOException {
    //content here
    }
```

i don't know how to fix this. can someone please help me?

Comment: You need to invoke the method `find()` using an object or make the method `find()` static.

Comment: Use Java naming conventions.